# Stopped Working: FB.ui with method: 'feed' suddenly quit working

Tags: facebook, feed, fb.ui

This question is similar to: [Facebook Error 191 on canvas app using FB.ui() for the 'feed' dialog (worked before, stopped working last week)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9934470/facebook-error-191-on-canvas-app-using-fb-ui-for-the-feed-dialog-worked-bef) which was never answered.

Starting today, after the user likes the page and enters the contest, the share dialog which presented itself stopped working and gave:

```
API Error Code: 191 
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

when logged in as an admin and just an error occurred for other users.  This tab has been running well for a while now.  I have confirmed it with an associate of mine.  They did make a change to another part of the app (yesterday and today) but the sharing was still working until this afternoon.  They did not change the part that generates the dialog.

The tab is: https://www.facebook.com/MedjoolDates/app_355398587864294

Anyone have any insight?  Feel free to use 'cancel' rather than sharing and fake data to sign up, then unlike the page if you wish.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, there is a bug posted on Facebook Developes here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273845842724431

Comment: Thanks!  I checked for bugs last night but must have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much without seeing your code.

One thing to check, make sure your redirection_uri is exactly as your domain registered with FB and that you include a trailing / ie http://www.myurl.com/ rather than http://www.myurl.com

I can't answer why it changed, but I had that error fixed by the above change before.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Am developing a new app with FB.ui feed functionality, which worked OK yesterday and today it gives the same error as OP.

Went back and checked an > 1 year old app with the same functionality; same error. I cannot see any other solution, than the FB dev team has changed something and not given notice.

Comment: Hm this should have been a comment, I see. Still rather new to SO, sorry.

Comment: The dialog works when accessing the app outside of Facebook. If trying inside a page-app, this message appears